# Using pivot and then counting the values in each pivot column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

| Agent_id | break_id | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 15 |
| 1 | 2 | 12 |
| 1 | 2 | 12 |

I used pivot to get this structure:

| Agent_id | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 24 |

The problem is that I need to get the count for the pivoted columns, in the example I need to have  a structure like this:

| Agent_id | 1 | 2 | count1 | count2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 24 | 1 | 2 |

And I'm not sure on how to do it ... this is the query so far.

```
DECLARE @COLUMNS VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @QUERY nVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @COLUMNS = COALESCE(@COLUMNS + ', ','') + QUOTENAME([break_id])
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT [break_id] FROM test) AS B
ORDER BY B.[break_id]


  SET @QUERY = '
SELECT agent_id,
    '+@COLUMNS+' 
FROM (
SELECT TOP (1000) 
      agent_id,break_id,time_inbreak 
  FROM test  
) as pivotData 

PIVOT (
    SUM(time_inbreak)
    FOR break_id IN ('+@COLUMNS+') 
) as pivotResult

'

EXEC sp_executesql @QUERY
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are your column names dynamic? If not you don't actually need dynamic sql for this

Comment: Hi. Yes they are dynamic. In the report server i dont have access to each client database, only a view with all the data. From there i have to give a lot of parameters to the query to make it dynamic. Also a lot of data is stored in historic databases, which further complicates the query. I reduced the example to make it more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `PIVOT` can only pivot a single column. But we can do multiple columns using conditional aggregation `SUM(CASE WHEN...` and `COUNT(CASE WHEN...`:

```
DECLARE @COLUMNS VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @QUERY nVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @COLUMNS = COALESCE(@COLUMNS + ', ','') +
    'Sum' + QUOTENAME([break_id]) +
    ' = SUM(CASE WHEN break_id = ' + break_id + ' THEN time_inbreak END), Count' +
    QUOTENAME([break_id]) + ' = COUNT(CASE WHEN break_id = ' + break_id + ' THEN 1 END)'
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT [break_id] FROM test) AS B
ORDER BY B.[break_id]
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);


  SET @QUERY = '
SELECT agent_id,
    '+@COLUMNS+' 
FROM (
SELECT TOP (1000) 
      agent_id,break_id,time_inbreak 
  FROM test  
) as pivotData 
GROUP BY agent_id;
';

PRINT @QUERY
EXEC sp_executesql @QUERY
```

I must say, I'm not sure how safe it is to aggregate the columns like that, especially in the face of parallelism. Preferably use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE`. At the very least I have added `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` to prevent parallelism

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i get the general idea. Your query gives me an error (Incorrect syntax near '='.), but i will try to fix it.